# Fetched Data Doesn't Show

Tags: php, html

Good Day,
I have a .php file witch has HTML code in it. I'm trying to show fetched data from my table and show the results in an HTML table. The problem is that when I echo date() function in  tag it shows with no issue but when I try to show data from my table it doesn't show at all. I have checked my SQL connection and I have no error. Below is my entire codes for the page. Please help me. Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
include("Telegram.php");
include("sqlconfig.php");
include("kayhanexbot.php");
$a = $datatable["transaction_date"];
?>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li>
      Step 1: Transaction Details
  </li>
</ul>
<table id="customers" style="width: 100%">
  <tr><th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th></tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 25%">Date</td>
    <td style="width: 75%"><?php echo $a; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 25%">Rate</td>
    <td style="width: 75%"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 25%">Amount</td>
    <td style="width: 75%"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 25%">Reason for Transfer</td>
    <td style="width: 75%"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<ul>
  <li>
      Step 2: Personal Information in Iran (Sender)
  </li>
</ul>
<table id="customers" style="width: 100%">
  <tr><th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th></tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 25%">First Name</td>
    <td style="width: 75%"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 25%">Last Name</td>
    <td style="width: 75%"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 25%">Address (postcode)</td>
    <td style="width: 75%"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 25%">Mobile Number</td>
    <td style="width: 75%"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 25%">Email</td>
    <td style="width: 75%"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<ul>
  <li>
      Step 3: Personal Information in Australia (Receiver)
  </li>
</ul>
<table id="customers" style="width: 100%">
  <tr><th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th></tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 25%">Date</td>
    <td style="width: 75%"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 25%">Date</td>
    <td style="width: 75%"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 25%">Date</td>
    <td style="width: 75%"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 25%">Date</td>
    <td style="width: 75%"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<ul>
  <li>
      Step 4: Identification
  </li>
</ul>
<table id="customers" style="width: 100%">
  <tr><th colspan="2">Photo ID</th></tr>
  <tr>
    <td colsapn="2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my function in "kayhanexbot.php":

```
function GetAllData($db, $chat_id)
{
  $sql = "SELECT a.chat_id,
                b.transaction_date,
                b.transaction_rate,
                b.transaction_amount,
                b.transaction_reason,
                c.transaction_fname,
                c.transaction_lname,
                c.transaction_address,
                c.transaction_mobile,
                c.transaction_email,
                d.bank_acctname,
                d.bank_name,
                d.bank_bsb,
                d.bank_acctnumber,
                d.rcvr_address,
                d.rcvr_email,
                d.rcvr_mobile,
                e.id_image

              FROM UserInfo AS a
              INNER JOIN IrtoAusUser_step1 AS b ON a.chat_id = b.user_id
              INNER JOIN IrtoAusUser_step2 AS c ON a.chat_id = c.user_id
              INNER JOIN IrtoAusUser_step3 AS d ON a.chat_id = d.user_id
              INNER JOIN IrtoAusUser_step4 AS e ON a.chat_id = e.user_id
              WHERE chat_id = '$chat_id'";
              $res = $db->query($sql);
              $row =  $res->fetch_assoc();
              return $row;

}
```

Below is the upper part of kayhanexbot.php:

```
<?php
$bot_id = "552964777:AAFu5jtOUZC-Npkmcn71nhDbYeNMz8Z01PM";
$telegram = new Telegram($bot_id);
$text             = $telegram->Text();
$chat_id          = $telegram->ChatID();
$message_id   = $telegram->MessageID();
$name             = $telegram->FirstName();
$family           = $telegram->LastName();
$username         = $telegram->Username();
$callback_data    = $telegram->Callback_Data();
$callback_query   = $telegram->Callback_Query();
$callback_chat_id = $telegram->Callback_ChatID();
$datatext = $telegram->ReplyToMessageID();
$chatid = GetChatInfo($db, $chat_id);
$tDate = GetTDMessage($db, $chat_id);
$datatable = GetAllData($db, $chat_id);
$a = $datatable["transaction_date"];
$b = $datatable["transaction_rate"];
const SITE_URL = 'https://kayhanex.com.au/kayhanexbot/img/';
```

Comment: try `var_dump $a;` to show what you have fetched from table.

Comment: Also show the code that is actually fetching the data.

Comment: @CKWong var_dump show NULL

Comment: @CBroe I added my function.

Comment: And, have you verified that this actually returns data …?

Comment: try execute your SQL query directly on your phpmyadmin (in case you have) to verify if there will be any result by your criteria... step by step...

Comment: I'm creating  a Telegram Bot and it shows correctly in Telegram Bot. I also checked my query through phpMyadmin and it fetches correctly

Comment: @ParvizKhorraminejad I doubt how you can say `I also checked my query through phpMyadmin and it fetches correctly` as you mentioned the `var_dump` shows `NULL`

Comment: You have showed us the function `GetAllData()` and then there should be somewhere you call this function and return the fetched result, right? Show that part of code please.

Comment: @CKWong I updated the code in question

Comment: @CBroe Yes I can confirm results are showing in MySQL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170273/discussion-between-ck-wong-and-parviz-khorraminejad).

Comment: Do a `var_dump($datatable);` after your includes, please, so that we can see the actual data structure.

Comment: @CBroe It's NULL!!!!!!!